# Integration of JIRA with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, jira, jira-rest-api

Could anyone specify the ways to integrate JIRA with TortoiseSVN to track the issue details? What URL should be specified in URL section, what are the other parameters needed? Is there anything you have to do on JIRA side to ensure the integration?

Answer (score 28):

I had lots of problems when reading TortoiseSVN documentation on the subject. Here are my findings about the integration. To integrate Jira and TortoiseSvn, a set of instructions should be performed. This guide suppose that your jira server is available through this url: http://192.168.10.10:8090. In addition, suppose that your project name in Jira is SVNTEST.

1. Install svn plugin for jira on your jira server. use [this link](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SVN/JIRA+Subversion+plugin) for more info.
2. Install the Jira plug-in for TortoiseSvn in your clients. It can be downloaded from [this link](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/10017) or [this one](http://csharptest.net/projects/jirasvn/).
3. For all the folders in your repository, set the flowing properties:

[image]

Add Jira setting to your TortoiseSvn. To do this follow the steps below:

- Right click on your code folder and from the TortoiseSvn menu, select settings item.
- Under hook scripts click on issue tracking integration.
- Click the Add button.
- Under the working copy path, enter the path of your source code.
- Under the provided select the only available item namely CSharpTest.Net.SvnPlugIn.MyPulgIn
- Under the parameters, enter the url of your Jira server, i.e. http://192.168.10.10:8090.
- After confirming the dialog, enter the username and password of your Jira server.
- To test whether the installation is complete, try to commit a set of changes. In the commit dialog, you should see a button namely Jira Issues. By selecting it, you should see your Jira issues within a new dialog.

Comment: thanks for ur post its helpful, but how to identify the jira server location

Comment: always thank in S.O by a +. In addition, the location of the jira sever can be obtained from the url in the jira page of your browser.

Comment: I am not sure about the way you are using Jira. But, if you use the web interface, take a look at its url. On the other hand, it is better to get help from your jira server administrator.

Comment: localhost:8032/JiraLockedError this is the error that im getting while trying to access jira

Comment: Your jira server is shut down improperly. Search for a lock file in the jira installation folder. remove it and restart your jira server.

Comment: i have found  the lock file in jira and removed ,again i connected them to the local host ....it shows the same status as localhost:8032/JiraLockedError

Comment: check out this page: http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=195429049

Comment: Is it just me ... or is it really stupid to have to key in the location of my working copy when I right-clicked a folder to get to this dialog?

Comment: "After confirming the dialog, enter the username and password of your Jira server. ". I am not getting this prompt and on clicking "Jiras" button, the SVN is not listing down the jiras as well.

Answer (score 7):

Following the advice of @Avi, here are the details for integration with JIRA:

1. Set the following properties on the directory for which you want the integration to JIRA:

   - `bugtraq:url`: Example could be `http://my.server.url/jira/browse/<PREFIX-FOR-JIRA>-%BUGID%`. Please fill in the right information for `my.server.url` and `<PREFIX-FOR-JIRA>`. If you want to map for all projects in JIRA, the string could be `.../browse/%BUGID%`.
   - `bugtrac:logregex`: Regular expression for you JIRA Id. Depends on what you want to match, for all project use `/w+\-(\d+)`

   There are other alternatives for defining the properties, but these should do it.
2. Commit your changes to the svn properties, so that the properties will be included for all people doing a checkout of the same directory.
3. When doing now a commit on some of the files in the directory or subdirectories, include there the issue tag in the log message of Subversion.
4. TortoiseSVN will now show a hyperlink in the log message, when you open the log of the files or directories.

If you would like to integrate JIRA as well with Subversion, there is a [documentation how to integrate Subversion into JIRA](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA044/Integrating+JIRA+with+Subversion). You have to install then the [Subversion JIRA plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/SVN/Subversion+JIRA+plugin) in JIRA.

Comment: the requested url/....../ was not found on this server ...this is the error im getting....any help

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to @mliebelt's answer.

```
svn propset "bugtraq:logregex" "([A-Z]+\-\d+)" .
svn propset "bugtraq:number" "false" .
svn propset "bugtraq:url" "http://jira.company.com/browse/%%BUGID%%" .
svn propset "jira:url" "http://jira.company.com" .
```

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN has excellent documentation. Since the question isn't about integration with a *specific* issue tracker, I don't think I can do any better than the page on [Integration with Issue Trackers](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html).

Comment: JIRA Startup Failed

You cannot access JIRA at present. Look at the table below to identify the reasons

Comment: this are the issues faced when connecting jira with svn

Comment: @shaggy: It sounds like the problem is more in JIRA than in TortoiseSVN, but not knowing JIRA integration I don't know. I suggest you put more information into your question, such as the properties you set, the URL of your JIRA installation, and the full error message.

Comment: @Avi I respectfully disagree.  The documentation shows the TortoiseSVN dialog and then proceeds to list the properties, without any explanation as to the correspondence between properties and fields in the dialog.  For someone inexperienced with SVN this would likely not be any help.

Answer (score 1):

In JIRA 7.1 support of SOAP web-service has been ended and RPC plugin was deprecated  and REST is used instead of SOAP so you can't use the the plugin written by csharptest.net.

A generous developer write a new plugin for TortoiseSVN which support REST. You can find it [here](https://github.com/gmoore777/JiraSVN/releases/).