# Repositories and Bug Tracker tools that mine data and output databases?

Tags: git, svn, jira, bugzilla

Is there any tool available for mining JIRA (or other issue tracker) issues that exploit projects who make use of the JIRA plugin (or other plugin that can do the same) that connect repositories to the issue tracker and reproduce the results as databases?

An example of such tool for other issue trackers that mine issues and repositories is:

https://github.com/MetricsGrimoire/CVSAnalY
http://tools.libresoft.es/bicho

However, they do not connect issues to source code commits.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly do you want to do with such a tool?

Comment: I am interested on seeing which files are connected to a given issue

Answer (score 0):

JIRA is equipped with plug-ins to connect to many source control systems, i.e. SVN and git. As an example, for SVN, there is plug-in that [could be found here](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.plugin.ext.subversion). This plug-in parses the commit messages of your SVN repository and searches for specific patterns to see if the commits are connected to a JIRA issue or not. This integration is also possible for SVN client tools such as TortoiseSVN. Take a look at this link to find more about [integration of JIRA and TortoiseVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641950/integration-of-jira-with-tortoisesvn/8653480#8653480).

Comment: Hi,

I am not sure if was I who did not understand right or if my question clear but: I am not looking for the plugin that integrates. I already know it exists. What I want is a tool like bicho that makes use of such plugins and link files to issues and generate the data in a database. Bicho do mine repositories and transform into databases but it does not connect file to issues. Thanks for replying! :-)

Comment: Take a look at jira tables. There may be a set of tables that map issues to files in such a way that you need. In addition, you need a very specific tool that I do not think could be found on the web. I propose you to get the bicho tool and customize it for yourself.